# How do I open my jQuery modal as wide as my elements but no wider?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, modal-dialog, width

I’m using JQuery 1.12.4.  I have the following DIV, which I intend to open as a dialog.

```
<div id="loginBox" style="display:none">
    <div>Login/Sign Up</div>
    <div id="loginLogos">
            <a href="/auth/google"><img border="0" alt="Google" src="http://www.racertracks.com/assets/google_plus_icon-8d7622763257233cf58e0465806f58d7c4b82b85271c2d03d0e02b2fadc4ac76.jpg"></a>
            <a href="/auth/facebook"><img border="0" alt="Facebook" src="http://runtrax.devbox.com:3000/assets/facebook-b74d7c49fd91aa6ca76518bf46c7b75fa3b23f47028bea4b2ffaa39f5776dd91.png"></a>
            <a href="/auth/twitter"><img border="0" alt="Twitter" src="http://runtrax.devbox.com:3000/assets/twitter_icon-7dbf8db24c3ad328ea28cba340e4f53e033b64b149850324822cdb622d77f331.png"> </a>
 </div></div>
```

What I’m noticing is that when I reduce the width of my screen to around 320 pixels (to simulate a mobile browser width), the dialog is opening wider than the total width of the elements — there is a lot of white space to the right of the images.  See the Fiddle here -- https://jsfiddle.net/g4a60Lq7/3/ .  How can I make the dialog open as wide as the elements and no wider?  Below is how I’m opening the dialog …

```
  var opt;
opt = {
  autoOpen: false,
  modal: true,
  width: 'auto',
  dialogClass: 'noTitle',
  focus: function() {
    return $(this).dialog('option', 'width', $('#loginBox').width() + 50);
  }
};
$("#loginBox").dialog(opt);
return $("#loginBox").dialog("open");
```

**Edit:** Wanted to post the image in response to pritishvaidya's second plunker ...

[image]

Comment: Have you tried without the extra 50 pixels, but using outerWidth instead? Like so: return $(this).dialog('option', 'width', $('#loginBox').outerWidth());

Comment: By the way, it's better to store $("#loginBox") in a variable, since you're using it multiple times. It's not gonna give you a noticeable performance boost in this particular example, but it's a good practice to cache selector objects that are reused often, otherwise jQuery has to go through DOM every time and in the end that adds up to the loading times.

Comment: If I remove the "+50" at a regular screen size one of the logos wraps to the next line even though they shoudl all stay on the same line.

Comment: Isn't @DmitriyDemir's first comment the correct solution? See this jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/g4a60Lq7/4/.

Comment: No.  Compress the fiddle in your comment to 320 pixels of screen width and then open the dialog.  Notice the vast amount of unnecessary space to the right of the icons.  I'm looking to eliminate that.

Comment: I think you might need to change the css of the jquery ui.css that you are using as it gives unnecessary padding to the elements.So do u want a solution with that?

Comment: Sure, that would be great!

Answer (score 2):

You can try this jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/43f5qjc8/7/. Since the image source is not very reliable, here is another jsfiddle with smaller images from another source: https://jsfiddle.net/43f5qjc8/13/.

It involves some Javascript to calculate the minimial width needed to display the content, which may wrap on several lines. If there is a way to get the same result with CSS only, I haven't found it.

Here is the Javascript code:

```
$(function () {
    $('.opendialog').click(function () { openDialog(); });
    function openDialog() {
        var opt = {
            autoOpen: false,
            modal: true,
            width: 'auto',
            dialogClass: 'noTitle',
            focus: function () {
                var width = 0;
                $('#loginLogos > .logoRow').each(function () {
                    var x = $(this).position().left;
                    var w = $(this).outerWidth();
                    var tmpWidth = x + w;
                    width = Math.max(width, tmpWidth);
                });
                $('#loginLogos').width(width);
                var outerWidth = $('#loginBox').outerWidth();
                $('#loginLogos').width('auto');
                return $(this).dialog('option', 'width', outerWidth);
            }
        };
        $("#loginBox").dialog(opt);
        return $("#loginBox").dialog("open");
    }
});
```

The HTML markup:

```
<a href='#' class="opendialog">Open</a>
<div id="loginBox" style="display:none">
    <div>Login/Sign Up</div>
    <div id="loginLogos">
        <div class="logoRow">
            <a href="/auth/google"><img border="0" alt="Google" src="..."></a>
            <a href="/auth/facebook"><img border="0" alt="Facebook" src="..."></a>
        </div>
        <div class="logoRow">
            <a href="/auth/twitter"><img border="0" alt="Twitter" src="..."></a>
            <a href="/auth/linkedin"><img border="0" alt="LinkedIn" src="..."></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the CSS styles:

```
body
{
    background-color: gray;
}

#loginBox
{
    font-family: 'russo_oneregular';
    font-size: 20px;
    display: inline-block;
}

#loginLogos
{
    position: relative;
}

.logoRow
{
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Hi, This seems to work well however i notice at a scren size of 400 pixels the box shows three icons on one row and one icon on the second row.  Is there a way to get it so taht if not all four icons display cleanly on one line they can display two by two?

Comment: It should work if we group the icons in two sub-divs, inside `loginLogos`. I will modify my answer to get that result.

Comment: I updated my answer and the jsfiddle. The icons are now grouped in two separate divs. The size goes directly to 2 x 2 if the width cannot accomodate the 4 icons.

Answer (score 1):

Just use Bootstrap modal popup structure that is totally responsive.

1. no need custom css.
2. easily customize by bootstrap js attribute

   ```
   <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
   <div class="modal-dialog">   
     <!-- Modal content-->
     <div class="modal-content">
       <div class="modal-header">
         <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
         <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
       </div>
       <div class="modal-body">       

       </div>
       <div class="modal-footer">
         <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
       </div>
     </div>   
   </div>
   ```

https://jsfiddle.net/zigri2612/0o41yogx/

Answer (score 0):

You need a bit of CSS to modify the `max-width` of the modal and the box-sizing. Here's your modified example: https://jsfiddle.net/elektronik/3ez3tm3f/1/

The main change is `.ui-widget.ui-widget-content[class] { max-width: 90vw; }`.

[vw](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/length#Viewport-percentage_lengths) is a very useful modern, [widely supported](http://caniuse.com/#search=vw) CSS unit.

The few other changes (compared to your original fiddle) prevent the modal content from overflowing. `box-sizing: border-box;` is present in all [modern CSS resets](http://cssreset.com/).

Answer (score 0):

make the logo responsive in the css:

```
#loginBox img {
  width: 23%;
  height: auto;
}
```

and change the width from 'auto' to '80%' :

```
window.onload=function(){
  $(function() {
    $('.opendialog').click(function(){ openDialog(); });
      function openDialog() {
        var opt;
        opt = {
          autoOpen: false,
          modal: true,
          width: '80%',
          dialogClass: 'noTitle',
          focus: function() {
            return $(this).dialog('option', 'width', $('#loginBox').width() + 50);
          }
        };
      $("#loginBox").dialog(opt);
      return $("#loginBox").dialog("open");
    }
  });
}
```